# Cannot write xlsx to GCS from pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-cloud-storage

I have a strange issue.

I trigger a K8S job from airflow as a data pipeline. At the end I need to write the dataframe to a Google Cloud Storage as a `.parquet` and `.xlsx` files.

```
[...]
export_app.to_parquet(f"{output_path}.parquet")
export_app.to_excel(f"{output_path}.xlsx")
```

Everything is ok for the parquet file but I got an error for the xlsx.

> severity: "INFO"
>    textPayload: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://my_bucket/incidents/prediction/2020-04-29_incidents_result.xlsx'

I try to write the file as a csv to try

```
export_app.to_parquet(f"{output_path}.parquet")
export_app.to_csv(f"{output_path}.csv")
export_app.to_excel(f"{output_path}.xlsx")
```

I get the same message every time and I find the other file as expected.

There is any limitation to write a xlsx file ?

I have the package `openpyxl` installed in my env.

Comment: I tried to upload xlsx using  google-cloud-storage library with no issue... what is this  export_app is can you add some reference to this?

Comment: It's just a pandas dataframe. ANd like I said to_parquet and to_csv is working fine. Maybe gcs lib only is ok but the underlying of to_excel doesn't work as excpected.
Can you share your code to upload your file I wanna try something.

Answer (score 1):

As requested I am passing some codes how I created new xlsx file using directly gcs python3 api. I used [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) tutorial and this [api reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html):

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# Create the bucket object
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("my-new-bucket")

#Confirm bucket connected
print("Bucket {} connected.".format(bucket.name))

#Create file in the bucket
blob = bucket.blob('test.xlsx')
with open("/home/vitooh/test.xlsx", "rb") as my_file:
    blob.upload_from_file(my_file)
```

I hope it will help!